# Spring boot avoid multiple findBy

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I need to do certain checks before an insert into featureEntity :
If applcation is active, if it contains a certain version and if a version has some specific type of users.

```
AttributeEntity{
   int id

   String name;

   String code;

   @OneToMany
   List<ApplicationVersionEntity> applicationVersionEntites
}

ApplicationEntity {
   int id

   String name;

   String code;

   boolean isActive;
}

ApplicationVersionEntity {
   int id
   int major;
   int minor;
   
   @ManyToOne
   ApplicationEntity applicationEntity;

   @ManyToOne
   AttributeEntity attributeEntity;

}

FeatureEntity {
   int id
   
   @ManyToOne 
   ApplicationVersionEntity applicationVersionEntity;

   @ManyToOne 
   ApplicationEntity applicationEntity;

   String name;

   boolean toBeImplemented;
}
```

Currently i'm fetching the results by using mutiple findBy :

```
// fetching
ApplicationEntity app = applicatonRepo.findByCodeAndStatus("abcd",true);
AttributeEntity attribute = attributeRepo.findByName("xyz");
ApplicationVersionEntity appVersion = appVersionRepo.findByMajorMinorApplicationEntityIdAndAttributeEntityName(major,minor,activeApplication.getId(), attibute.getName());

if (application != null && appVersion != null && attribute != null){
  FeatureEntity feature = new Feature();
  feature.name("avoid multiple findby");
  feature.setApplicationEntity(app);
  feature.setApplicationVersionEntity(appVersion);
  featureRepo.save(feature);
}
```

Is there a better and faster way to do it ?
I found out about Criteria Builder but I'm unable to make it work.
If Cirteria Builder is the right choice, it would be extremely helpful to have an example of fetching and saving above.

Answer (score 0):

If the query is not dynamic, criteria builder wont add much.

You can use `@Query` to run a custom query where you can check all of your values, if JPA is not enough, you can try with a native query so you are not limited to JPA syntax

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE u.status = ?1", 
  nativeQuery = true)
User findUserByStatusNative(Integer status);
```

From here, the problem becomes, how to build a query to check your 3 tables, you can use UNION or something like that, so just that query is needed.

More info in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: I don't really understand how this avoids multiple findby operations, could you elaborate a bit more please ?